# How to create custom form validator in 2 input? i want to validate that one input number is always greater to one another

Tags: angular, comparison, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

How to create custom form validator in 2 input? I want to validate that one input number is always greater to another one.

```
  ValidateMaxMin(control: FormControl) {
    console.log(control.value.productMin);
    if (control.value.productMin != 0) {
      return { hasError: true };
    }
    return null;
  }



 this.productForm = this.fb.group ({ //form validator for create and update
      '_id': [ "" ],
      'productName': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/), Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]) ],
      'supplierId': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i), Validators.minLength(24), Validators.maxLength(24)]) ],
      'brandId': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i), Validators.minLength(24), Validators.maxLength(24)]) ],
      'categoryId': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i), Validators.minLength(24), Validators.maxLength(24)]) ],
      'productPrice': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/), Validators.min(1), Validators.max(99999)]) ],
      'productQuantity': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/), Validators.min(1), Validators.max(99999)]) ],
      'productMax': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/), Validators.min(1), Validators.max(99999)]) ],
      'productMin': [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/), Validators.min(0), Validators.max(99999), this.ValidateMaxMin ]) ],

    });
```

In above code, I can only validate one specific field, whereas my intention is to specify/get two fields and compare them.

Comment: I think this [link](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) might help you

Comment: Based on the examples, it is not clear to get the values of different input fields, and validate them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the validation method that will do what you want

```
static ValidateMaxMin(firstField: FormControl | AbstractControl | null,
                      secondField: FormControl | AbstractControl | null,
                      message = `one input number should alwasy be greater than another`
): ValidatorFn {
return (): ValidationErrors | null => {
  if (firstField && secondField && firstField.value >= secondField.value) {
    const notGreater = { notGreater: { message: message } };
    secondField.setErrors(notGreater);
    return notGreater;
  }
  notGreater!.setErrors(null);
  return null;
};
```

}

and an example how you can use it in your forms

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  firstField: ['', Validators.required],
  secondField: ['', Validators.required],
});
this.form.setValidators(Validators.passwordConfirming(this.form.get('password'), this.form.get('passwordConfirm')));
```